# Improve Browser Performance When Dragging Div Element Containing Thousands of Child Nodes

Tags: javascript, performance

This question has to do with creating complex user interfaces using javascript while keeping browser performance high.

Specifically, how to keep the browsers FPS from dropping significantly when dragging an element around on the screen that contains thousands of nodes.

I'm using javascript to generate form inputs based on a number of things:  First, there is several levels to this form, and each level then contains 3 sub levels which all contain 3 sub levels. To be exact, there is 3 parent levels, 3 sub levels to each parent, and 3 sub levels to those sub levels.  This makes a total of 27 containers I then generate form elements into.

Once the inputs have been generated for each of these 27 containers, there is over 2600 inputs within the main container holding everything, and this container is a jquery dialog.

I hope I've explained this clearly.  What I have is a jQuery dialog containing thousands of inputs, and when you drag this dialog around on the screen, it is very choppy, not smooth.

I figure the sluggishness is due to there being literally thousands of DOM nodes within the container being moved about.

How can I allow such a huge amount of elements be dragged about without the browsers FPS dropping significantly?

At first I was going to call this question "How to improve browser FPS when dragging a jQuery Dialog that contains thousands of inputs", but I renamed it to be a little more accurate.

EDIT: 
Whether I use jQuery dialog() to make the main container draggable or I use plain vanilla javascript, the performance is very sluggish.

EDIT 2: (What exactly I'm doing)
The thousands of inputs will never be filled out in the sense like a web form.  The inputs may or may not contain values input by the user that generates a style sheet in real time. I'm building a visual element builder so to speak.  Using the dialog full of inputs the user can set the styles on an array of elements. Basically I am giving full CSS control over a number of elements through a form.  Indeed its some what a little insane, if not impossible... but like Einstein said, “If at first, the idea is not absurd, then there is no hope for it” ... Anyways if I can pull it off it'll be quite like something that's never been built before.  As noted in my comment below, only a hundred inputs are actually visible at a time.

EDIT 3:
As a test, I removed 2/3's of all the inputs and the performances increases very noticeably.  Since all the elements don't need to be displayed at once, only when the user navigates to that section of the form, is there someway to have the DOM ignore them until they are actually needed?  What the user sees is only a fraction of how many inputs are actually present.

And thank you to everyone who has replied to my question, I appreciate your inputs (although I've already got a couple thousand of them... LOL).

Comment: Should be straight forward, don't generate 2600 inputs at once, do it as needed, or preferably not at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  At at a minimum a thousand inputs are needed right away.  The nature of the app requires all these inputs.  Can using a framework like react.js help with this?

Comment: Do the `input` elements need to be visible when dragging around?

Comment: No, not really, using a framework won't help much, if you have too many elements, you have too many elements. Who would ever want to fill out 2600 inputs, and what on earth would require that much input from the client.

Comment: also as @adeneo you need to give us some background info on what you are actually trying to achieve. Your use case sounds ludicrous at best

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - I've updated the question to explain exactly what I'm doing.  Concerning the inputs, only a hundred or so are actually visible at a time.

Comment: _" if I can pull it off it'll be quite like something that's never been built before"_ There's probably a reason for that.

Comment: @j08691 - I knew someone was going to say that :)

Comment: It's the new magnificent *"never ending contact form"* ... tada !

Comment: Well its not a contact form, just a form with thousands of inputs.  All the values don't even get posted actually, their values are combined and posted as one string.

Comment: Here's an interesting article that ponders my question about using something like react.js to speed things like this up: https://medium.com/tony-freed-consulting/what-is-virtual-dom-c0ec6d6a925c#.cmqnzl66u

Comment: Does someone want to explain why they downvoted my question?  I took a considerable amount of time to make sure the question was well structured and thought out.

Comment: this may help you https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas

Answer (score 0):

By setting display: none on any inputs not in the current view, the DOM ignores those nodes, and the form can be dragged about with no lag.

So the solution was really quite simple.  Set display: none on all containers that do not need to be displayed (as you can only see about 100 inputs at a time anyways), and the DOM ignores the nodes when redrawing the main container as it gets dragged around.

Problem solved :)